# Two servers (linux & windows) on shared domain w/o subdomains

Tags: linux, windows

I am currently looking to have 1 domain (Example.com) but would like to to have two servers on that domain. Linux to be the primary and windows to be the secondary.

If someone types in Example.com/page and that does not exist on the Linux server, then it will check the windows server for that path.

I want to accomplish this without sub domains.

Is this even possible? Could this be done in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a single domain (abcxyz.com) in two servers, we need to point two different IP's for the domain. The hostname/domain is a separate thing from IP address, so server A will have one IP, server B will have another one.

We can use DNS round-robin for both the servers, point the host/domainname to both IP addresses at once. Allowing multiple machines to participate in the domain is handled by DNS and needs to be set up on your DNS Server.

Shared hosting provider may or may not support this.